# How to add collection and document to Firestore in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can anyone help me figure out how I can store the userCredits for each user, instead of storing it in local storage? If possible, please dumb it down as much as possible, I never did anything similar. Thanks a bunch!

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { Firestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { FirestoreModule, doc, collection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideFirestore,getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CreditsService{

  constructor(private firestore: Firestore) {}

  private localStorageKey = 'userCredits'; // Key for the credit local storage

  // Load the user credits from local storage or set to 10
  private userCredits: number = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.localStorageKey)!) || 10;

  getCredits(): number {
    return this.userCredits;
  }

  minusCredit(num: number): void {
    if (this.userCredits - num >= 0) {
      this.userCredits -= num;
      localStorage.setItem(this.localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(this.userCredits)); // Store the updated user credits in local storage
    }
  }

  updateCredits(): void {
    /* console.log(collection(this.firestore, 'db'));
    collection(this.firestore, 'db').
    
    /* const userInfo = collection(firestore, 'users'); */
  }
}
```

I tried making a user interface and user service with this function

```
add10Tokens(user: ProfileUser) : Observable<any> {
    const ref = doc(this.firestore, 'users', user?.uid);
    const userData = { ...user, coins: 10};
    return from(setDoc(ref, userData));
  }
```

Is that a good start?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.